# Process A spawns Child B which spawns Child C. Child B dies before Child C. Child throws error. Does it bubble up to Process A?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

Let's say you have a process called Process A that spawns a Child B, and this Child B spawns a Child C which is child of Child B and grandchild of Process A.

Here's a visual:
Process A --spawns---> Process B --spawns---> Process C.

Now the scenario is that Process B dies before Process C. Then after a while, Process C dies. Will the exception bubble all the way to Process A or will it go nowhere because Process B, Process C's parent died before it did?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense. First, all processes return some value, but there is no inherent mechanism by which errors in a child process are passed up to a parent or other ancestor process. If a parent or ancestor can use waitpid() to wait on a specific process and get that processes return value. 

Also, C does not provide any mechanism for exception handling.

Maybe you can be more specific?

Comment: Process A will be wholly unaware of the existence of Process C.  In particular, A will not receive the death certificate from C — a process only gets the death certificates from its direct children.  There's a system process (usually PID 1, aka `init`) that inherits orphaned children and waits for them to die.  When B dies, `init` inherits C — not A.  There might be IPC mechanisms (such as a pipe created by A, inherited by B and used by C) that could help with detecting the death of C; but you'd have to code to handle that.

Comment: There was [a decent article about the orphaned process issue](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) (in relation to Docker) that gave a nice overview of the situation. It's a good read and explains in some more detail what @JonathanLeffler states so succinctly.

Comment: is the CLONE_PARENT flag what you looking for? so the parrent of process C will be A. see man clone